# Xampp: How to Make a Clean Uninstall to Get Old MySQL Installation Back?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp, mysql-workbench, lamp

I have since months a working version of MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I installed Xampp from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and now my old MySQL installation does not work anymore (e.g.: my existing databases are not visible anymore in MySQL workbench, the password seems to be another one).

How can I get my old version of MySQL working again?

It would be ok, if I loose Xampp.

(I see my databases in the filesystem at: `/var/lib/mysql/` and know that the old MySQL configuration is in `/etc/mysql/`)

I posted this question elsewhere, too.

Comment: I found this blog post from 2013: https://coranguweb.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/how-to-uninstall-xampp-from-ubuntu/. Can somebody tell me whether it is still valid?

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

- First option: Your database password has been changed. You need a process to recover password:

  1. Stop MySQL server (sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop)
  2. Start MySQL server with parameter --skip-grant-tables (sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &)
  3. Connect to server as root (You can use workbench without password, or command line order: mysql -u root)
  4. Set a new root password (Use workbench or command line: update mysql.user set password = PASSWORD("newpass") WHERE user = 'root'; flush privileges;)
  5. Restart MySQL service (sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart)
- Second option: Your new MySQL xAMPP are using the same port as your old installation. You can check it on logs.

  - You can change port configuration on one of the installations. Search for my.cnf file and change directive "port = 3306" with another number.
- Third option: Your new MySQL installation override the old one. You need to recover the old files from data folder, and copy it to the new installation.

  - This process does not work if the new MySQL installation are older than the old one. In that case, download a new xAMPP package with a newer MySQL, or delete xAMPP package and install MySQL from apt-get.